# C++ Compiler shows just numbers, not the right output

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++.

It should give me a random "forest" with 20 lines and 30 columns with trees (X) and empty spaces. For the trees should stand a X and for no tree an empty space.

the compiler just giving me random numbers like 888888888888..... or other numbers back .. I have no idea why.

Here is my Code:

```
void printForest();

int Forest [20][30];

int main (void)
{
int tree, line, column;

srand(time(NULL));

for (line = 0 ; line < 20; line++)

    for (column = 0; column < 30; column++)
    {
        tree = rand() % 100 + 1 ;

        if (tree > 0.6 * 100)
        tree[line][column] = ' '; 
        else
        tree[line][column] = 'X';       
    }
        cout << tree [20][30] << endl;
}
printforest();

cin.get();
return 0;
}

void printforest()
{
int line, column;
for (line = 0 ; line < 20; line++)
{
    for (column = 0; column < 30; column++)
    {
        cout << forest[line][column];
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: What is `Wald`?

Comment: You really get output?  This code should not even compile as is.

Comment: Is `Wald` supposed to be `Forest`?

Comment: `tree [20][30]` is also indexing an int. Is that allowed?

Comment: It seems like you may have confused `Walf` and `Forest` along with `tree` and `Forest` in some cases.

Comment: This looks more like C (or C++98) than modern C++... Maybe read more up-to-date books, targeting C++14 or later.

Comment: Ignoring the code completely, it's likely `forest` is a table of `int`. It's elements are `int`s and will print as `int`s. If you want to print their character representations, either make `forest` a table of `char` or cast the elements to `char` explicitly before printing.

Comment: "the compiler just giving me random numbers like 888888888888" - The compiler is a program that takes your code and converts it to native code that can run on your machine. Generally when you say *the compiler gives me...* that will be taken to refer to either an error message during compilation, or the output of the compiler (i.e. the actual produced native code). In this case I think you mean that your code is producing random numbers at run-time (rather than the compiler producing random numbers). If you did mean the compiler then please reproduce the exact error message it gives.

Comment: The code you show here still does not compile.  It's not the code that's giving the output you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, being charitable, that code is a little wild. I've cleaned it up a bit, the key changes were to replace all occurrences of `Wald` with `Forest` and to change the array access to access `Forest` in main. The code generates a character table `printForest` prints out the table row by row, I hope that's what you were after :)

```
#include <iostream>

void printForest();

static const int maxRows = 20;
static const int maxColumns = 30;
char Forest [maxRows][maxColumns];

int main ()
{
    int tree, line, column;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (line = 0 ; line < maxRows; line++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < maxColumns; column++)
        {
            tree = rand() % 100 + 1;

            if (tree > 0.6 * 100)
                Forest[line][column] = ' '; 
            else
                Forest[line][column] = 'X';       
        }
    }
    printForest();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void printForest()
{
    int line, column;
    for (line = 0 ; line < maxRows; line++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < maxColumns; column++)
        {
            std::cout << Forest[line][column];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Recommend marking what you changed and why so that this is more than a simple Code-only answer.